# Learn the bayes net structure with latent variables while testing (but observed while training)

Tags: bayesian, graphical-model, bayesian-network

I want to use Bayesian network for data which has 5 types of variables which are inter-dependent on each other. Out of that, 1 variable is observed only while training but it is unavailable during testing stage. I must say that, the hidden variable at test time *(henceforth referred to as `H`)* has a considerable impact on the output.

My question is that can I use any scheme which will work in above scenario. I have read about Bayesian network structure learning algorithms such as MCMC and greedy search. Most of them require fully observed data (which I have during training!). I thought of modelling `H` as a hidden variable but I am not sure if that's a good / correct idea.

Just for additional information: I have an idea about the initial configuration of the structure since I am solving a real-world problem.

Comment: You can represent factor analysis models as graphical models, do you have some idea of what the structure of the data is? Given some fairly non-restrictive assumptions, it sounds like factor analysis might fit your criteria.

Comment: @NickThieme For structure, I actually can give exact ordering of ancestors and descendents. To start with, I can also provide a connection between them. However, I am not sure how to model the H variable which is available (observed) during training and unavailable (completely hidden) during testing. Well, I can skip that during training and hope that the network may learn the relationship. But that seems to me like a lot of wastage of data. Could you please elaborate on factor analysis models as graphical models. I am a novice, I have just finished reading some tutorials on Bayesian networks.

Comment: Regarding structure of data: the data is multidimensional and continuous. Particularly, the observations are multidimensional and the result is a scalar (both are continuous).

Comment: Google factor analysis and state space models and check out the lecture notes from cmu, they'll do a better job of expanding how you can view FA as a PGM since they can do pictures. Also, and I should have asked you this as my first question, how is the variable available during training but not testing? Did you train your model on one batch of data, collect new data and are training on that?

Comment: @NickThieme Ok. Here is the situation. I have (say) 5 types of variables. Out of that 1 is output, others are input. Out of 4 input variables, 1 is extremely costly to compute at run-time but output variable equally depends that "costly" variable as compared to other 3. Therefore, I was thinking if I could have modeled it as a hidden variable during training (but provide values for it). So this becomes complete data and I will use EM algorithm to learn parameter and structure of network. At test time, output and "costly variable" are hidden and I will ask evidence only for output variable.

Comment: Honestly, given that one of your variables is observed and is strongly related to the response but you're choosing not to use it, I have to say it sounds like you're parameter estimates will be biased. Without knowing why this one variable is more costly to incorporate into your model, I don't think I can help anymore.

Comment: @NickThieme *<< Without knowing why this one variable is more costly to incorporate into your model>>* As I said, computation of that variable at testing time is costly. However, I must say that, "costly variable" can be expressed in terms of another input variable `v` as `a*v+b` and generally difference between `v` and "costly variable" would be small. Therefore, I thought that network would be able to learn the relationship. Anyways, thanks for your help. If you have any additional pointers, it would be great.